# map + reduce don't work as expected for 2d array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I have a 2D array of ints and I'm trying to perform the same action in all rows using map + reduce.

For example, if I'm having a 3x3 array

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

and I'm trying to calculate the sum for each row (expected outcome would be)`[6,15,24]`

Then I plan to firstly reduce each row into its own sum with a reduce:

```
[1,2,3].reduce((sum,each)=>each+sum,0)
```

and then repeat(map) it into all the rows.

However when I combine the map and reduce like the following

```
a.map(x=>{x.reduce((sum,each)=>{each+sum}),0})
```

instead of getting the expected outcomes I'm actually getting`[undefined,undefined,undefined]`

not sure why is that happening?

Comment: `a.map(x=>{x.reduce` You forgot to return the reduced result.

Comment: `a.map(x => x.reduce((sum,each) => each + sum, 0))` `<--` remove the curly-brackets.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
a.map(x=>x.reduce((sum,each)=>each+sum))
```